# Does Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi 4B support x86-64 and ARM64?

Tags: raspberrypi, arm64

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my Raspberry Pi 4B and i want to use it like if i would use normal PC.
Does it suppport AMD64 and x86-64 platform like on PC version of ubuntu or not ?

Comment: The question is backwards: The hardware provides the architecture platform, not the OS. The OS and applications must be compatible with the arm64 (not amd/x64) platform that the Pi provides. Ubuntu does have an arm64-compatible build, and arm64-compatible builds of most repository applications. A few architecture-specific applications (like Virtualbox) are obviously unavailable for different architectures.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi is an ARM-based device, so uses ARM-builds of packages and applications. Depending on what applications you want to run, there shouldn’t be too many issues aside from speed.

Answer (score 0):

raspberry pi is an arm system - that's not compatible with AMD64 or x86-64

you have to download an arm version of ubuntu

there's even a special ubuntu version for raspberry pi : here : https://ubuntu.com/raspberry-pi